# Pentagram Diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Can somebody help me make this commutative diagram look more aesthetic?

```
% compile with LaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pictexwd,dcpic}

\begin{document}
\begindc{\commdiag}[500]
\obj(0,0){$F(V)$}
\obj(2,0){$F(W)$} 
\obj(-1,1){$F'(U_1)$} 
\obj(3,1){$F'(U_3)$}
\obj(1,2){$F'(U_2)$}
\mor(-1,1)(1,2){}
\mor(-1,1)(3,1){}
\mor(-1,1)(0,0){}
\mor(-1,1)(2,0){}
\mor(3,1)(2,0){}
\mor(1,2)(0,0){}
\mor(1,2)(2,0){}
\mor(1,2)(3,1){}
\mor(3,1)(0,0){}
\mor(3,1)(2,0){}
\mor(0,0)(2,0){}
\enddc      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on _look more aesthetic_?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Create the image in latex, you will see that the arrows crash into the objects.

Comment: You may want to shorten your arrows like `\mor(0,0)(2,0)[200,200]{}` or alike. `200` are the number of DC-units which should be shortened. One value stands for 'at beginning' and the second one for 'at start'.

Comment: Is your question answered by one of the posts? If not, please edit your question. If yes, please accept one answer here by clicking the check mark to its left and I will delete my comment here. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

The following example sets the corners of the pentagram by a node with polygon shape of a regular pentagon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=5,
      minimum width=30mm,
    ] (PG) {}
      (PG.corner 1) node (PG1) {$F'(U_2)$}
      (PG.corner 2) node (PG2) {$F'(U_1)$}
      (PG.corner 3) node (PG3) {$F(V)$}
      (PG.corner 4) node (PG4) {$F(W)$}
      (PG.corner 5) node (PG5) {$F'(U_3)$}
    ;
    \foreach \S/\E in {
      1/3, 1/4, 1/5,
      2/1, 2/3, 2/4, 2/5,
      3/4,
      5/3, 5/4%
    } {
      \draw[->] (PG\S) -- (PG\E);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The height can be reduced by specifying `yscale`:

```
\node[..., yscale=.75] (PG) {}
```

> [image: Result yscale=.75]

---

The lines

```
 (PG.corner 1) node (PG1) {$F'(U_2)$}
 ...
 (PG.corner 5) node (PG5) {$F'(U_3)$}
```

can also be written as:

```
  \foreach \t [count=\i] in {F'(U_2), F'(U_1), F(V), F(W), F'(U_3)} {
    (PG.corner \i) node (PG\i) {$\t$}
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

I can just offer two solutions with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\edgelentgh}
\setlength{\edgelentgh}{3cm}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={0cm,between origins},column sep={0cm,between origins}] % setting seperators to zero for easier manipulation
&[.3090169944\edgelentgh]
&[.5\edgelentgh] % above value times golden ratio
F'(U_2)\arrow{ddl}\arrow{ddr}\arrow{drr} 
&[.5\edgelentgh] 
&[.3090169944\edgelentgh] 
\\[.5877852523\edgelentgh]
F'(U_1)\arrow{urr}\arrow{rrrr}\arrow{dr}\arrow{drrr} 
&&&& 
F'(U_3) \arrow{dlll}\arrow{dl} 
\\[.9510565163\edgelentgh] % above value times golden ratio
& 
F(V)\arrow{rr} 
&& 
F(W) 
& 
\end{tikzcd}
\]      

% This example is given in the tikz-cd manual:

\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\node (P0) at (90:.8506508084\edgelentgh) {$F'(U_2)$};
\node (P1) at (90+72:.8506508084\edgelentgh) {$F'(U_1)$} ;
\node (P2) at (90+2*72:.8506508084\edgelentgh) {$F(V)$};
\node (P3) at (90+3*72:.8506508084\edgelentgh) {$F(W)$};
\node (P4) at (90+4*72:.8506508084\edgelentgh) {$F'(U_3)$};
%
\path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
(P0) -- (P4) edge (P3)
(P0) edge (P3)
(P0) edge (P2)
(P1) edge (P0)
(P1) edge (P4)
(P1) edge (P3)
(P1) -- (P2) edge (P3)
(P4) edge (P2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it seems satanic, lol

Answer (score 6):

A [MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/metapost.html) solution using the [`boxes`](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf) package, included in a LuaLaTeX program to make it easier to typeset.

The differents nodes are linked thanks to this `link` macro:

```
  def link(suffix a, b) =
    drawarrow a.c -- b.c cutbefore bpath a cutafter bpath b 
  enddef;
```

As its syntax suggests, it deletes the parts of the line before the boundary of the first node and after the boundary of the second, before drawing the actual arrow.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \everymplib{input boxes;
    def link(suffix a, b) =
      drawarrow a.c -- b.c cutbefore bpath a cutafter bpath b 
    enddef; 
    beginfig(1);}
  \everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 1.75cm;
    boxit.fv("$F(V)$"); fv.c = origin;
    boxit.fw("$F(W)$"); fw.c = (2u, 0);
    boxit.fpu1("$F'(U_1)$"); fpu1.c = (-u, u);
    boxit.fpu2("$F'(U_2)$"); fpu2.c = (u, 2u);
    boxit.fpu3("$F'(U_3)$"); fpu3.c = (3u, u);
    drawunboxed(fv, fw, fpu1, fpu2, fpu3);
    forsuffixes a = fv, fw, fpu3, fpu2: link(fpu1, a); endfor
    forsuffixes a = fv, fw, fpu3: link(fpu2, a); endfor
    link(fv, fw); link(fpu3, fv); link(fpu3, fw);
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`xypic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic) package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix{
 &           & F'(U_2) \ar[dddl] \ar[dddr] \ar[drr]                 \\
    F'(U_1) \ar[urr] \ar[rrrr] \ar[ddr] \ar[ddrrr]  &&          &&
    F'(U_3)  \ar[ddl] \ar[ddlll]                                    \\
 &  F(V) \ar[rr]                                    &&  F(W)
}
$$
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image: Picture of the pentagram with better arrows but bad spacing]

This is slightly better than what you have but the spacing doesn't look really good. But you can add an empty row to make it more tall:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix{
 &           & F'(U_2) \ar[dddl] \ar[dddr] \ar[drr]                 \\
    F'(U_1) \ar[urr] \ar[rrrr] \ar[ddr] \ar[ddrrr]  &&          &&
    F'(U_3)  \ar[ddl] \ar[ddlll]                                    \\
                                                                  \\
 &  F(V) \ar[rr]                                    &&  F(W)
}
$$
\end{document}
```

Now it outputs:

[image: Picture of the pentagram]

Which looks pretty good to me.

The advantage of `xypic` is that it is extremely simple and you can use a matrix-like syntax to define the diagram.

Comment: Please, avoid `$$` in LaTeX code.

Comment: If you just want the 5-cycle this simplifies to $\xymatrix{
           &            & q_0 \ar[drr] \\
q_4\ar[urr]&            &             &            &q_1  \ar[ddl] \\
\\
           &q_3 \ar[uul]&             &  q_2\ar[ll]
}
$

Answer (score 3):

And just in plain Metapost, with nice line crossings.

I switched `F(V)` with `F(W)` to make the loop simpler.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
numeric R; R = 120;
picture t[];
t1=thelabel(btex $F'(U_1)$ etex, (0,R) rotated 72);
t2=thelabel(btex $F'(U_2)$ etex, (0,R));
t3=thelabel(btex $F'(U_3)$ etex, (0,R) rotated -72);
t4=thelabel(btex $F(V)$    etex, (0,R) rotated -144);
t5=thelabel(btex $F(W)$    etex, (0,R) rotated +144);

path arc;
bboxmargin := 5; 
for i=1 upto 5:
  draw t[i];
  for j=i+1 upto 5:
     arc := center t[i] -- center t[j]
            cutbefore bbox t[i] cutafter bbox t[j];
     undraw arc withpen pencircle scaled 4;
     drawarrow arc;
  endfor
endfor
endfig;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 4.4 of the manual of DCpic shows a pentagon shaped diagram. Re-using that code, you get:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pictexwd,dcpic}

\begin{document}
\begindc{\commdiag}[70]
\obj(6,4)[4]{$F(V)$}
\obj(18,4)[3]{$F(W)$} 
\obj(2,16)[5]{$F'(U_1)$} 
\obj(22,16)[2]{$F'(U_3)$}
\obj(12,22)[1]{$F'(U_2)$}
\mor{1}{2}{}\mor{1}{3}{}\mor{1}{4}{}
\mor{2}{3}{}\mor{2}{4}{}
\mor{4}{3}{}
\mor{5}{1}{}\mor{5}{2}{}\mor{5}{3}{}\mor{5}{4}{}
\enddc
\end{document}
```

[image]